# The concept of the creation of a trapdoor in NP-complete or NP-hard problems

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard

I am reading the book [*An Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4939-1711-2). In its chapter 7, there is the following statement:

> In real world scenarios, cryptosystems based on NP-hard or NP-complete problems tend to rely on particular subclass of problems either to achieve efficiency or to allow the creation of a trapdoor.

**Questions:**

Is is possible to explain what does it mean the phrase "*to allow the creation of a trapdoor*"?

Thanks for any help

Comment: It is explained in chapter 1, page 47, what a trapdoor is. Chapter 2, page 63, explains it in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "trapdoor" function is a function which is hard to compute, but will become very easy (or a lot easier) to compute if you have some specific knowledge.

The classical example is solving y = x^3 (modulo n) where n is the product of two very large primes; it is the basis of RSA encryption and practically impossible to solve given x and n, unless you are given the two primes p, q such that n = pq.